# Code optimization-Declaring views referenced by more than one method and implementing onclicklistener

Tags: android, optimization, onclicklistener, instance-variables

I am often confused whether to create an instance views and use it in different methods OR to avoid using instance views and pass views between different methods?Is it good practice to implement onClickListener?And is it good practice to initialize views separately in different methods and avoid using instance views?
Which is the better approch among below three?

1.**Avoiding instance variables and NOT implemeing onClickListener**

```
public class XYZActivity extends BaseActivity {
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initViews();

    }
private void initViews() {
        ImageView ivScanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBanner);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferName);
        TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferText);
        TextView tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferDetail);

menthodXYZ(ivScanner,tvName);

tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}); 
tvText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}); 

tvDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}); 
}
```

2.**Creating instance variables and implementing OnClickListener**

```
public class XYZActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private ImageView ivScanner;
private TextView tvName,tvText,tvDetail;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initViews();

    }
private void initViews() {
        ivScanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBanner);
        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferName);
        tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferText);
        tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferDetail);
  tvName.setOnClickListener(this); 
  tvText.setOnClickListener(this);
  tvDetail.setOnClickListener(this);
  ivScanner.setOnClickListener(this);


...
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.ivScanner:
                ...
            break;
            case R.id.tvName:
              ....
            break;
            case R.id.tvText:
              ....
            break;
            case R.id.tvDetail:
              ....
            break;
        }
}
```

3.**If a variable is needed in different methods then initializing it separately in different methods to avoid instance variables and implementing OnClickListener**

```
public class XYZActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initViews();

    }
private void initViews() {
        ImageView ivScanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBanner);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferName);
        TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferText);
        TextView tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferDetail);
        ...
}
private void methodXYZ()
{
           ImageView ivScanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBanner);
            TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferName);
            TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferText);
            TextView tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferDetail);
...
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      ImageView ivScanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBanner);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferName);
        TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferText);
        TextView tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferDetail);
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.ivScanner:
                ...
            break;
            case R.id.tvName:
              ....
            break;
            case R.id.tvText:
              ....
            break;
            case R.id.tvDetail:
              ....
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - **findByView** is considered to be an expensive operation that is desirable to perform once, so your variant 3 is very expensive from this point of view.

Secondly, if your *...* in the 2nd variant means

```
menthodXYZ(ivScanner,tvName);

tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}); 

tvText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}); 

tvDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
```

--> your code with single `onClick` has no sense =)

But if it means:

```
menthodXYZ(ivScanner,tvName);
tvName.setOnClickListener(this); 
tvText.setOnClickListener(this); 
tvDetail.setOnClickListener(this);
```

--> you can use it, and I think that it is the best of your variants, because you:

- you can use all of your views instances in any method of your `Activity`
- you avoiding of additional `findById` method calling

Why your first variant is not good (it's only my personal opinion) - you put all of your clicks handlers logic into one single place, and if click handlers has a lot of code, it will be hard to debug it.

...
Also, I can suggest you another variant =) You can use [ButterKnife library](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) from Jake Wharton. It will remove all your boilerplate code for creating views instances and `onClickListeners`:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.app_version)
    TextView appVersionTextView;

    @BindView(R.id.my_image_view)
    ImageView myImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbinder.unbind();
    } 

    @OnClick(R.id.my_need_click_view)
    public void clickToMySuperView() {
        Log.i("TAG", "click to my super view!");
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.my_need_click_view_2)
    public void clickToMySuperView() {
        Log.i("TAG", "click to my super view 2!");
    }

    ...

}
```

**UPDATE**

Look on the following peace of code:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);

        myImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        myTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.my_image_view:
               // special code for image view
               break;

            case R.id.my_text_view:
                // special code for text view.
                break;

            default:
                // no actions.
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

In this peace of code we initialize our views instances only once, then set click listener to them. `onCreate` method, according to `Activity` lifecycle, calling only once (if `Activity` creates in the first time, or recreates it's state after destroying). In `OnClick` method our views not initializing, we just need `id` from `View` parameter.

Then, look on the following peace of code:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView myImageView;
    private TextView myTextView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);

        myImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        myTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.my_image_view:
               // special code for image view
               break;

            case R.id.my_text_view:
                // special code for text view.
                break;

            default:
                // no actions.
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

In this case we initialize our views instances and saves them into our `Activity` object. But, again, we initialize them only once - in `onCreate` method. And again, in `onClick` method we don't search this views again through `findById` method.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: While first approach might not be good in terms of readability of code,but don't you think it is better in terms of performance and optimization as we don't need to create instance views or variables with that approach.Second approach improves the readability of code by putting on click events inside single method but with that we need to create instance views for all the views we are using inside onclick

Comment: It depends on what you exactly need. If you don't need use your views instances in further work, then you don't need save them inside your `Activity` object at all. You can just find them on view through `findById` method, then set `onClickListener` to them. 
About performance and optimizations... How many views you need to save? If this number is small (I mean, less than 100), than may be you don't need to think about this little memory consumption.

Comment: Also, in your first approach, you create `onClickListener` for every view - it creates another memory consumptions =) From this point of view, the second approach is much better, as it creates only one 1 listener =)

Comment: if i don't need to use view instances in further work and i find view and  set onClickListener as u said like -`findViewById(R.id.view1).setOnClickListener` , then everytime click event occurs on view then  findViewById operation is performed and as you said  findViewById is expensive operation then will it not effects performance adversely?

Comment: yeah but often we need to access other views on click of particular view and it is not ideal that we call findViewById each time..so i think it is better we declare views as instance views..

Answer (score 2):

Option #3 should be avoided - you should not call `findViewById()` more than once per `View`. It is not just about performance (these calls become performance issues only if made in tens and hundreds e.g. `ListViews`), but also about code readability.

I'm usually defining fields for all `Views` which are being used in a particular component. This way you can (kind of) get a clue about what the component does by just looking at its fields' definitions. It is also probable that you will need references to some of these `Views` in other methods in the future, therefore this approach increases maintainability.

As for whether one should use anonymous listeners or make the enclosing component implement `OnClickListener` interface - it is mainly a personal preference choice. My rule of thumb: if anonymous listeners for all `Views` of interest fit single page of code - I go with anonymous; if not - I make the containing component implement `OnClickListener` interface and handle all clicks in a separate method.

So, in your case, I would go with something like this:

```
public class XYZActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private ImageView ivScanner;
    private TextView tvName;
    private TextView tvText;
    private TextView tvDetail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initViews();

    }
    private void initViews() {

    }
        ivScanner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBanner);
        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferName);
        tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferText);
        tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOfferDetail);

        tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        tvText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        tvDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and if I would need to add a listener to `ivScanner`, then I would refactor all the listeners into a single method.

**Performance:**

Please note that anonymous classes have some performance cost associated with them. You can listen to [this talk by Jake Warthon](http://jakewharton.com/exploring-java-hidden-costs/) - he did a great job investigating and explaining it. However, I think that int this case, readability and maintainability outweigh minor performance gains.